# UnhandledException - How to know what control made the application crash

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have already delivered my app to customers but they are complaining that sometimes the app crashes, and they need to relaunch it.

I told them to describe what they were doing and what option / window they were using when the app crashed, unfortunately none of them was able to say something. So I decided to make a `Global UnhandledException` function.

I updated the app with below `Global UnhandledException` code and I'm receiving the error messages through email but my concern now is that I'm not going to be able to locate what control caused that error in order to fix the problem.

So far, the error message I receive from 4 clients is `Index was outside the bounds of the array.` and I'm able to fix that but I'm not sure what VB control causes the problem as the app has many ListBoxes on each Window, and different controls.

I just want to know whether there's a way to locate via `(e.Exception.[control name])` the exact control that raises the error.

Below is my Global UnhandledException code

```
Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
    Try
        errorMsg = e.Exception.Message     'Store the error message in order to be sent via email to Support/Fix Departement via email

        e.ExitApplication = False

        thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf sendGlobalExcept)
        thread.Start()
    Catch

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I would suggest rather than using just the message, send `exception.ToString()` as that will include the stack trace which will allow you to see on which line the error occurs

Comment: Thanks stuartd. **That's really what I wanted.**  I appreciated that. It's solved !!!

Comment: by the way, my app is multithreaded as seen above and use Backgroundworker too. Will **UnhandledException** catch multithreading exception as well?

Comment: "Will UnhandledException catch multithreading exception as well?" - No, it only catches exceptions on the main UI thread.  Instead handle [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: If you know the solution now, post that as an answer and accept it. There are many global exception handlers you can register (more than what the comments have mentioned), so you should carefully search via Google.